# Ctrl+C incorrectly mapped in Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, sigint

I was playing around with my keyboard shortcuts and accidentally mapped a command to the Ctrl+C shortcut. Now I can't stop programs running in the terminal with Ctrl+C and I have no idea of how to restore this functionality.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Go in to your Keyboard Shortcut settings, find where Open a Terminal is listed and change it to something else.. The default for that one is "ctrl+shift+t". Save, close.. And you should be fine..

Comment: Not quite... I want to kill programs running in the terminal using SIGINT (the default behavior of Ctrl+C), which isn't listed in the Keyboard Shortcut settings.

Comment: I use SIGINT like a crazy person (who uses SIGINT all the time).

Comment: Dude - [you should totally drop that and try tmux.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question).